# WordPress - Get Categories & Posts With Type Article

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to fetch all categories and the post that belongs to the category, to fetch all categories, I am using the following code

```
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'article-category',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    'child_of'      => 0
);
$get_categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
```

To fetch all post with type articles I am using this code

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
}
```

This gives me the list of all categories and list of all post of type articles in a separate loop, however what I want is something in this line

```
Category 1
    - Post 1 Title
    - Post 2 Title
    - Post 3 Title
Category 2
    - Post 4 Title
    - Post 5 Title
    - Post 6 Title
    - Post 7 Title
    ...
...
```

I am basically trying to fetch all categories and all post of type article that belongs to this category, I tried many different ways, but nothing seems to work out, how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: why not you use this plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/
It have a shortcode. you can use it to print post as per passed category

Comment: I cannot use the plugin, the reason Is, I am developing a custom UI element that requires all this to be displayed in specific format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try below answer, as you need to apply word press code further in loop to get data in appropriate format. You can set UL / LI as per your specific design by remove  and

tag from mine code after successfully data display.

```
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'article-category',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    'child_of'      => 0
);
$get_categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
foreach($get_categories as $get_category){
    $ids[] =  $get_category->term_id;
}
$finalCatPostData = '';
foreach($ids as $id){
    $finalCatPostData .= '<h2>'.get_cat_name( $id ).'</h2>';
    $args = array(
    'category'         => $id,  
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'post_type'        => 'article',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($posts_array as $post){
        $finalCatPostData .= '<p>'.$post->post_title.'</p>';
    }   
}
echo $finalCatPostData;
```

**Output:**

```
cat 1
post 1 of cat 1
post 2 of cat 1

cat 2
post 1 of cat 2
post 2 of cat 2

cat 3
post 1 of cat 3
post 2 of cat 3
```

Comment: It is not working, I also tries this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166564/category-in-not-working-on-custom-post-type

Comment: Above code is tested in my word press , can you please debug with passing argument ? it should work btw..

Comment: I had to use tax_query for the reason mentioned in the link posted above and it is working, thank you for the hint, your solution helped me in going the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite exactly the solution but you could follow the below logic

1) Get The Categories

```
  $cat_args = array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'article-category',
        'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'parent'        => 0,
        'hide_empty'    => true,
        'child_of'      => 0
    );
    $get_categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
```

2) Loop through each category and get posts, add them to a final array

```
$mFinalArray = []; // init empty array

foreach($get_categories as $category){


$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => $category, // fetch all posts that are in current $category
));
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $mFinalArray[$category][] = get_post(get_the_ID()); // add post under current category
}

// reset loop here

}
```

Output would be like that :

```
Array(

 [a_category_name_example1] => array(many_posts_here_of_this_category),
 [a_category_name_example2] => array(many_posts_here_of_this_category),
)
```

Consider playing a little with the above code cause it may not be exactly correct.

Comment: Wrapping WP_Query in the loop I fear will have performance issues considering I have approximately 20 categories and between 10-15 articles per categories.

Comment: I see, ok can you edit the question, i want you to `var_export` a post array and a category array. You can create one array from those two doing exactly the same thing.